# How to return value can be provided as an argument, to be used instead of None in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

If we try this in shell:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="not-exists"]/text()').extract_first(default='not-found')
```

it will return as 'not-found'. The problem is when I try to remove first and do this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="not-exists"]/text()')[1].extract(default='not-found')
```

It doesn't work. I really need this.

Comment: Please provide a (minimal) full example of your input and what you have tried. For example, what is in `response`?

Comment: response.css('h5::text')[1].extract() 
if i make it like this
response.css('h5::text')[1].extract(default='not-found') . it doesnt work

Comment: because some pages may have it and some pages may not have it . so i need to use [1] in my response anyway and if it not have it i want it to be return as 'not-found'

Answer (score 0):

I think that you doing it all wrong. If you want to extract the first element just use extract_first() or extract() with more accurate Xpath pattern, using hardcoded indexes is a bad practice.

Anyway, I think that a better way is to try to return the string or default value.

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="not-exists"]/text()').extract_first() or 'not-found'
```

Comment: i want it to work here as well : response.xpath('//div[@id="not-exists"]/text()')[1].extract()

Comment: for example : response.xpath('//div[@id="not-exists"]/text()')[1].extract() or 'not-found'

Comment: This is not safe way to work cause you can get IndexOutOfRangeException if the returned list is empty.

Comment: i know this is why i want to replace it with something else if its not exist

Comment: @AtotheK did you find some better way for the solution? I'm also facing the problem.